# Getting text within <a > tag inside <p> tag

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

Hi i have been trying to get all the text part within the div - p tags up to the hr tag so somebody gave this xpath

```
//div[@class="entry"]/*[not(preceding-sibling::hr | self::hr)]/text()
```

which works fine but this ignores the text part within the <.a> tag in the p tag
any ideas to grab that text as well?

```
<div class="entry">
   <p> some text</p>
   <p> some text2</p>
   <p> some text3</p>
   <p> some text4
       <a href='somelink'> this text here i want to get through xpath</a>
       some text5
   </p>
   <hr>(up to this hr tag)
   <p> some text5</p>
   <hr>
   <p> some text6</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way might be `//div[@class="entry"]/*[not(preceding-sibling::hr | self::hr)]//text()` though I might prefer to simply select the elements `//div[@class="entry"]/*[not(preceding-sibling::hr | self::hr)]` and use the string value.

Comment: thank you idk why i didnt try adding // but it works for me also I would like to know whats the second method you are describing?

Comment: what iam doing is 
response.xpath('xpath here//text()').get() or .extract()

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pull data based on xpath.

```
//div[@class="entry"]/p[0]
//div[@class="entry"]/p[1]
//div[@class="entry"]/p[2]
//div[@class="entry"]/p[3]
//div[@class="entry"]/p[4]
//div[@class="entry"]/p[5]
```